# Numerical integration over a Random Forest Regression Model

Tags: random-forest, integral, numerical-integration

I am trying to compare the accuracy of a polynomial model and a Random forest regression model in predicting a variable Y but also the integral of this variable ,

With the polynomial model, it is clear how to compute its integral, however, I am wondering if applying a numerical integration over the prediction range will make sense in the case of Random forest regression model,

Answer (score 3):

What method of numerical integration do you have in mind? Many numerical integration methods rely on the smoothness of the integrand. Random forests are not smooth. Furthermore, in most cases, numerical integration does not work well beyond 2 dimensions. Safer is Monte-Carlo integration, which works no matter what smoothness and dimension.

But trees consist of locally constant functions on axis aligned rectangles, and random forests are linear combinations of those trees. This means you can integrate analytically, you do not need approximations. The only problem is practical. Depending on the program you use to fit the model, you may not have (easy?) access to the data of the underlying trees, which you need to calculate the individual integrals.